# I Installed Odoo 14 but when i run the terminal it shows odoo 15

Tags: installation, odoo-14, odoo-15

I installed Odoo 14 but when i run my terminal it shows odoo version 15.
When I try to Install the module Hr_payroll it throws the following error.

```
<data name="dashboard assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_dashboard/static/src/js/dashboard_view.js"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_dashboard/static/src/js/dashboard_renderer.js"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_dashboard/static/src/js/dashboard_model.js"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_dashboard/static/src/js/dashboard_controller.js"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_dashboard/static/src/js/dashboard_model_extension.js"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/web_dashboard/static/src/scss/dashboard_view.scss"/>
        </xpath>
    </data>
```

I want to run odoo 14 and install the module hr_payroll.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this command in terminal

```
git checkout 14.0
```